# Python Appium Element.text returns jsons tags instead of real translation

Tags: python-3.x, ngx-translate, appium-android

I'm trying to get text from element using element.text but instead of text displayed on screen i've get tags from translation json.

ngx-translate library has been used in application.

```
 textA = self.HelperSelenium.getTextFromElement(self.Starter.WELCOME_VIEW())
```

Code for the class:

```
class HelperSelenium:
        def getTextFromElement(element):
            if (element==None):
                raise Exception("getTextFromElement element is None")
                return
            if (element): return element.text
            else: return "ELEMENT NOT FOUND BY WEBDRIVER"
```

I expect "Welcome to Ionic Menu Starter in Portuguese"
Actually I have : "'HELLO Ionic Menu Starter MENU.PORTUGUESE'

It has been taken from translation json file:

```
{
  "HELLO": "Welcome to ",
  "MENU" : {
      "PORTUGUESE" : "in Portuguese",
      "ENGLISH" : "in English",
      "FRENCH" : "in French"
  },
```

I have no idea how to get full literal which is displayed on device screen.
Please help.

Comment: Try changing 'return element.text' for 'return element.get_attribute("text")' or 'return element.get_attribute("name")'